# NOAA vDatum which WGS84(*) reference for data created using ESRI WGS 84

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, vertical-transformation, agisoft-photoscan

I have an ESRI shapefile that use the WGS84 using latitude and longitude.  The ESRI text for this coordinate reference system refers to EPSG 4326.  The Z values reference the NAVD88 vertical datum and I want to use NOAA vDatum to convert the vertical datum from NAVD88 to EGM96.  vDatum requires the in-data horizontal reference system and for WGS84 there are the following choices; *WS84(G1674)-use ITRF2008, WGS84(G1150)-use ITRF2000, WGS84(G873)-use ITRF96, WGS84(G730)-use ITRF91, WGS84(G1762-use IGS08)*.  I have tried using WGS84(G873)-use ITRF96, and WS84(G1674)-use ITRF2008 and the difference is a few centimeters for the resulting Z values.

I am assuming that the best choice would be WGS84(G873)-use ITRF96 since the dates match but I would like to clarification that this is the best choice.

Comment: Do you know when the data was collected? Plus, what is its accuracy? Also was it converted to WGS84 from NAD83 (what version)? You may need to convert the WGS84/ITRF coordinates to NAD 1983 OR one of its re-adjustments to convert the heights.

Comment: Without this information, there's no way to know the accuracy of the converted heights.

Comment: @mkennedy  The NAVD88 surface model was collected in 2006 using LiDAR with <4cm error listed in the report for flat smooth surfaces.  The X and Y values were captured December 2017 using a mapping grade GNSS.

Comment: @mkennedy Just to clarify, the Z values in the attribute table were derived from the 2006 LiDAR and added to the shapefile using ArcGIS-ArcToolBox-3DAnalyst-Fuctional Surface-Add Surface Information.  The X and Y values were collected with the mapping grade trimble and exported out of GPS Pathfinder office using a WGS PRJ file exported out of ArcCatalog.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.